# Comparison of reaching probabilities of two Markov chains

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process, coupling

Let $N_n:=\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$. Given two finite states Markov chains $\big(X^{(j)}_i\in N_n\}\big)_{i=0}^\infty$ for $j\in\{1,2\}$. Pr$(X^{(1)}_{i+1}=b|X_i=a)>$Pr$(X^{(2)}_{i+1}=b|X_i=a), \,\forall a<b, a,b\in N_n$. Pr$(X^{(1)}_{i+1}=b|X_i=a)\le $Pr$(X^{(2)}_{i+1}=b|X_i=a), \,\forall a\ge b, a,b\in N_n$. Is it true that Pr$(X^{(1)}$ reaches $b|X^{(1)}_0=a)>$Pr$(X^{(2)}$ reaches $b|X^{(2)}_0=a), \,\forall a<b$, and Pr$(X^{(1)}$ reaches $b|X^{(1)}_0=a)\le$Pr$(X^{(2)}$ reaches $b|X^{(2)}_0=a), \,\forall a
\ge b$?

Does a coupling argument help to resolve this problem?

Comment: $X^{(1)}$ goes directly to $b$ from points to the left of $b$ more often than $X^{(2)}$ does, while it goes directly to $b$ from points to the right of $b$ less often than $X^{(2)}$ does? That seems like it should be an incomparable situation, intuitively, even if you are forced to start on one side or the other (because what if you jump to the other side in the first step?)

Comment: @Ian: Why is it incomparable? I do not see a counterexample in starting on one side or jumping to the other side. In the extreme case of $X^{(1)}$ moving only to the right and $X^{(2)}$ moving only to the left, the inequality holds.

Comment: I think with the exact way you've stated your hypotheses, my answer is correct. But it relies on the assumption that $b$ is allowed to be absorbing, which is a bit sensitive to the exact way that you wrote things.

Comment: Though wait, in your quantifiers, is $b$ fixed and you are quantifying over $a$, or are you quantifying over pairs $(a,b)$? I think I may have misread the question.

Comment: That said, if that's right, then there is a workaround: simply take $X^{(2)}$ to be absorbing at $1$ while $X^{(1)}$ is irreducible. Then $X^{(1)}$ will always reach whatever $b$ you like, while $X^{(2)}$ will fail to do so sometimes even if started to the left of said $b$.

Comment: @Ian: It is over all and arbitrary pairs $(a,b)$. Your counterexample seems to violate the premise. Can you edit your answer to reflect the premise?

Comment: Working on it already.

Comment: Does this satisfy the hypothesis now, or did I misinterpret again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the way you have set it up, $X^{(1)}$ moves to the right more consistently than $X^{(2)}$, and $X^{(2)}$ moves to the left more consistently than $X^{(1)}$, in the sense that if their transition matrices are $P$ and $Q$ respectively then $p_{ij}>q_{ij}$ if $i<j$ and $p_{ij} \leq q_{ij}$ if $i \geq j$.

So consider:

- $q_{11}=1$, $q_{ij}>0$ if $i \neq 1$
- $p_{ij}>0$ for all $i,j$.
- Otherwise require the above inequalities.

Now $X^{(2)}$ may fail to visit, say, $2$, even if it begins at a state to the right of $2$, because it could potentially skip directly to $1$ and then be stuck there forever. Meanwhile $X^{(1)}$ will visit all states with probability $1$.

Comment: 1) If both $X$'s are irreducible or all transition probabilities are positive, each $X$ visits all states with probability $1$, correct? Then there is no sense comparing, right? 2) What if $p_{11}=q_{11}=1$ and $p_{ij}>0, q_{ij}>0,\, \forall i>1$, otherwise the inequalities in the premise are satisfied?

Comment: @Hans 1) Yes. 2) So technically the way you wrote everything you can't have $p_{11}=q_{11}$; but if you allow that anyway, then I think it holds but I am not sure how to write the proof.

Comment: My formulation does allow $p_{11}=q_{11}$ if you read it again. The reducibility gives non-one visiting probability to the non-absorbing states so we can compare, right?

Comment: @Hans Sorry, you can have $p_{11}=q_{11}$ but you can't have them both equal to $1$ in your formulation because then $p_{12}=q_{12}$ which is prohibited. Anyway yeah, once both chains have an absorbing state then the problem is nontrivial.